# Are the build scripts of packages in the Ubuntu main/universe repos public?

Tags: command-line, compiling, repository, source-code

Are the build scripts of packages in the Ubuntu [Main/Universe repos](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) public? An example package is [Blender](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/blender).

I want to compile a package by myself, but it is not well-documented on the package's main page.

Comment: You can download the entire package use `apt source` which includes everything the developers need. With Ubuntu, all packages are built on launchpad, and not by users/devs (except in early stages of testing; though lp will do that too via PPAs or *personal package archives* which is an intended purposes of PPAs), with reports being stored on lp & emails/notices of build/failures only being sent as required (even to IRC), and yes that includes 'main' & 'universe'.

Comment: @guiverc with `apt source` is there a standard way of building? For example, `make x86_64` or `make arm64`

Comment: `apt source` will just download the source for the package, so you can build it locally, or make changes and then upload to PPA or build it yourself. There are many guides that walk you through the steps so you can build locally; but `apt source` just grabs the package source so it can be built (including package controls). https://packaging.ubuntu.com/singlehtml/ , https://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html etc that can be useful, with many teams having their own docs too (or you can Debian's, same detail by written by different people thus can be useful if you're stuck)